# Preserving Failure Type with Combine's tryMap

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I'm using Combine to write a simple web scraper. I'm trying to map the returned data to a string of HTML, throwing `ScraperError`s at each possible failure point. At the end, I want to pass this string to my `htmlSubject`, which is a `PassthroughSubject<String, ScraperError>`, for further processing.

```swift
    urlSubscription = URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .mapError { _ -> ScraperError in // Explicitly stating my failure type is ScraperError
                ScraperError.unreachableSite
            }
            .tryMap { (data, response) -> String in
                guard let html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                    throw ScraperError.readFailed
                }

                return html
            }
            .subscribe(htmlSubject) // <-- Not allowed because failure type is now Error
```

However, I'm finding that `.tryMap` is erasing my `ScraperError` to a regular `Error`, preventing me from chaining my `htmlSubject` to the end:

> Instance method 'subscribe' requires the types 'Error' and
>   'ScraperError' be equivalent.

Is there an obvious way around this that I'm missing, or am I getting tripped up conceptually? I'm thinking of this chain as building blocks in a large function that maps `<(Data, URLResponse), URLError>` to `<String, ScraperError>`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Handled in my online book: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsmap.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mapError` to convert back to `ScraperError` after the `tryMap`:

```
urlSubscription = URLSession.shared
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .mapError { _ -> ScraperError in // Explicitly stating my failure type is ScraperError
        ScraperError.unreachableSite
    }
    .tryMap { (data, response) -> String in
        guard let html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            throw ScraperError.readFailed
        }

        return html
    }
    .mapError { $0 as! ScraperError }
    .subscribe(htmlSubject)
```

If you don't want to use `as!`, you'll have to pick some other case to map to:

```
    .mapError { $0 as? ScraperError ?? ScraperError.unknown }
```

If you don't like that either, you can use `flatMap` over `Result<String, ScraperError>.Publisher`:

```
urlSubscription = URLSession.shared
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .mapError { _ -> ScraperError in // Explicitly stating my failure type is ScraperError
        ScraperError.unreachableSite
}
.flatMap { (data, response) -> Result<String, ScraperError>.Publisher in
    guard let html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
        return .init(.readFailed)
    }
    return .init(html)
}
.subscribe(htmlSubject)
```

Comment: Cheers Rob, I really like the `.flatMap` solution. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I find the resulting code to be a bit more readable when wrapping Rob's `flatMap` approach into an extension:

```swift
extension Publisher {
    func flatMapResult<T>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Output) -> Result<T, Self.Failure>) -> Publishers.FlatMap<Result<T, Self.Failure>.Publisher, Self> {
        self.flatMap { .init(transform($0)) }
    }
}
```

The code example above would then become:

```
urlSubscription = URLSession.shared
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .mapError { _ -> ScraperError in // Explicitly stating my failure type is ScraperError
        ScraperError.unreachableSite
    }
    .flatMapResult { (data, response) -> Result<String, ScraperError> in
        guard let html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return .failure(.readFailed)
        }
        return .success(html)
    }
    .subscribe(htmlSubject)
```